# What is the "T" set?

Tags: notation

I am reading an engineering paper and it references a "T" set in the same way that one would reference the set of complex numbers with $\mathbb{C}$, or the set of real numbers with $\mathbb{R}$". What is this set? I can't find it in any list of set symbols.

Comment: May be transcendental numbers..

Comment: Damn. I forgot my mind reading cap in the office and I won't be there before Wednesday.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{T}$ is sometimes used to denote the [circle group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group), also known as $S^1, U(1)$, or $SO(2)$. This is the [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)) of complex numbers of absolute value $1$ under multiplication.

Comment: That's the first thing that came to my mind. But without knowing what paper it is, I don't think it's possible to say anything with certainty.

Comment: The paper is titled "Synchronization in Complex Networks of Phase Oscillators: A Survey" and was written by Florian Dorfler and Francesco Bullo.

Comment: @Spencer Read the section "1.4 Preliminaries and Notation", subsection "Geometry on the $n$-torus", where the notation is defined. Short answer, Qiaochu Yuan is right.